# How to insert parameter to url from html form?

Tags: html

I have a link class.php?event=donbass2012
and I have a html form. How to send value from form to url to get link like this:

class.php?event=donbass2012&class=f1a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a normal GET form, with whatever inputs you need.

```
<form action="class.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="event" value="donbass2012">
    <input type="hidden" name="class" value="f1a">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<form name="input" action="class.php" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="event" value="donbass2012" />
   <input type="hidden" name="class" value="f1a" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Browsers will destroy any existing query string when submitting a form, so that will lose the event parameter.